# Create a specific .vimrc for git commits usage?

Tags: vimrc, git

There is probably an easy solution for this, but here it goes :
whenever I do a `git commit`, an error appears (copied hereunder). Vim then starts, some of my `.vimrc` features are enabled, some are not.

Since I don't need all of my .vimrc options to just write a commit, I thought that a possible solution for that would be to **create a `.vimrc` file specifically for git commits**, but I don't know how that should be done?

**Error :**

```
Error detected while processing /home/homehome/.vimrc:
line  106:
E518: Unknown option: foldenable
```

Comment: Note that `foldenable` is local to a window thus you shouldn't put it in your vimrc at all since the setting will not be applied on all of the windows. I also think that if your problem is that you have an error in your vimrc you should correct the error rather than changing your vimrc :)

Comment: @statox Thank you very much for the 'local window' precision !
Regarding the error in the `.vimrc`, it seems however that the error only pops up when Vim is called from `git commit`, and never happens otherwise...
Also, where should I put the `foldenable` option then ?

Comment: You're welcome :) Does that solve your problem with your git commits?

Comment: @statox not yet, I posted the comment without meaning it, then edited it to explain more in details, which I guess you thus did not see :)

Comment: Are you certain you're using the same Vim executable in both instances? What does `:version` report in regular Vim and in git commits?

Comment: @Rich There were indeed two versions of vim : "small" for `git` and "huge" for my usual vim...
`git config --global core.editor vim` worked ! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is strange that the error just appear with `git commit` -- I guess you have two versions of Vim installed, and the one used by git is older/have less features and thus complain about that option.

You could try [to configure you git editor](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration) passing the full path of the Vim you normally use.

In any case, I agree with the comments on your question: you should fix your `vimrc` instead of creating another one. And that setting a option which is local to window doesn't make much sense -- it would be better in a [`filetype-plugin`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_43.txt.html#filetype%2dplugin) or in a [`modeline`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#auto%2dsetting).

As a last resort you could check if the option is available before setting it. In [`:help 'foldenable'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27foldenable%27) it says it requires the `folding` feature, so you can if that feature using [`has()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#has%28%29), or maybe check directly the option as explained in [`:help exists()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#exists%28%29).

Comment: "Re"-telling `git` that I wanted Vim for editor (`git config --global core.editor vim`) worked. Thanks !

Comment: @Feffe glad it worked!